# Where is the acronym menu in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

With the following code Visual Studio + Resharper notifies me that the following example Class does not meet the naming convention:

```
public class AB2CManager {
  // TODO: Write some code
}
```

When I put my cursor on the class name and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> it gave me the option to add the acronym AB to my acronyms list. However, in my case AB2C is the full acronym.

How can I manually edit this list of acronyms? I would like to add the full acronym so that hypothetical class `ABManager` is still not accepted by the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp50/Coding_Assistance__Naming_Style.html#To_create_a_list_of_abbreviations

If you just want to edit the list of abbreviations, use only the lower part of the form; where you can enter, delete or update any entry there.

For example, on my current project I have a field called NIFEmisor, NIF being a spanish ID number. I've added 'NIF' to that box and no more trouble.

Comment: Right. The path to the target Options page has changed in ReShaper 6.x though: it's now available via ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > [Language] > [Language] Naming Style